# drupal 7 get title token without anchor tag

Tags: views, nodes, webforms, navigation, tokens

I am using a view with a "content:link" field to display a custom link for each content in my block.

I have job listing in block and want to add a link for each job "Apply". When users click on "Apply" it will redirect to a webform with title of the respective job.

So in my View under the **REWRITE RESULTS** setting I have selected **Rewrite the output of this field** and added my custom anchor tag like below:

```
 <a href='20?id=[title]'>Apply Now</a>
```

It works but it's putting title with anchor tag. So the output URL becomes

```
 <a href='20?id=<a href="mysite/node/23">Team leader</a>'>Apply Now</a>
```

Here I want the value of title token, without an anchor tag. Is it possible? Or any other way to do this job?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue. As described below :

We can use fields as token only whose we selected a block field.

I have selected title as block field with link to content node. so it was taking title anchor as token. I have removed tick for  "Link to node" option from title field settings.

Now it's working fine.

Comment: yea, you have to uncheck the "Link to Node" option or else it will always generate an A-tag fragment. Glad you figured it out.